# How to avoid too much running apps?

Tags: task-management

Meanwhile I have many running apps in my phone and I found that a lot of apps keep running because they "trick". They register as a `boot receiver` so they start with the phone, then register as a "new app installed" receiver and so on. The do everything to keep running. If you kill them, some of them start again because the creat a service which checks if they are running.
I guess these apps do that because they want to transmit information about the user or phone.

What can I do against those apps when the phone is not rooted? The task killers that I checked do not work. I think they are fake.

(With a rooted phone the [Autorun manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rs.autorun&hl=en) seems to work good)

Comment: Have you tried looking at hibernation applications for example Greenify?

Comment: [Disable autostart on boot and restrict background execution](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209345/218526)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you may want to look into **hibernating** the applications as opposed to killing them with a task-killer.

The former is advantageous, since it takes care of all background services of the given app and prevent them from waking up, until such a time when the user executes them.

One candidate in mind perhaps the popular one is [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&hl=en). One [XDA user(lioux)](https://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=5141926)  has been generous enough to provide a detailed mechanism of Greenify;

> It (Greenify) is a GUI (graphical interface) that lets you select applications
>   that **you don't want running on the background**, starting automatically
>   when the phone boots or responding to intents.
>
> It provides useful data
>   about running applications so that you may make an informed decision.
>   It uses the android command `am` to stop an application. It will no
>   longer start during phone boot, respond to registered intents or be
>   triggered by alarms from the system:

```
 am force-stop package.name
 am start package.name
```

> Everything it does is **temporary**. The `am` command does not touch the
>   installed files or any configuration information. It merely tells the
>   system to "forget" about the application.
>
> The system re-learns some of the intents again the next time the
>   application is executed: launched by the user or launched by another
>   application.
>
> *If the application does not behave as expected after being awakened,
>   remove it from Greenify then reboot your phone.*
>
> Some applications do
>   not re-register events when executed. Sometimes, they only do it at
>   boot. Furthermore, applications might have specific "relationships"
>   that might be disturbed when one is stopped (location service for
>   instance).

---

Up to date, Greenify has been constantly updated, to include handy features even for non-rooted device (although the functionality is limited compared to using it on rooted device and even much better when integrated with the Xposed module)

> Most of the basic features of Greenify **work out of the box on
>   non-root devices,** still some useful additional features require a
>   one-time privilege escalation procedure different than normal
>   permissions, which is enforced by Android system, using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb)

For that see: [How to grant permissions required by some features on non-root device?](https://greenify.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/749142-how-to-grant-permissions-required-by-some-features)

*Note: Some users have observed some certain functions are still limited despite granting permission through adb (may possibly be a bug in experimental releases)*

Acknowledgements

- [Greenify](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=40475823&postcount=1200)
- [How to grant permissions required by some features on non-root device?](https://greenify.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/749142-how-to-grant-permissions-required-by-some-features)
- [Greenify with ADB permissions?](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/greenify/greenify-adb-permissions-t3523570)