# Why does my android use so much ram?

Tags: stock-android, ram, android-sdk

I recently bought a realme xt phone 8gb ram varient. I usually get only 4 gb ram free and rest of the ram used by system. So i want to know that it's usual for 8gb ram system to take up to 4 gb ram for system process.

[I attached two screenshot taken from the 'developer options -> running services'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcF3V.jpg)

Comment: Because of this: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory-overview#SwitchingApps

Comment: When i restart my phone i got around 4.5 gb ram free from 8gb when no app is running in background.

Comment: Many system/user apps start after reboot automatically: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209345/218526 The Home/Launcher screen you see is also an app. Lock screen is also an app (System UI). The screenshot you attached is also Settings app.

Comment: I wonder why take upto 4gb ram. 4gb is lot of ram

Comment: Android tries to make use of available resources in best way, to keep a good balance between energy consumption and performance for better user experience. Keeping RAM free isn't always a good thing: https://www.howtogeek.com/128130/htg-explains-why-its-good-that-your-computers-ram-is-full/. But if you hold a different opinion, find out apps using large RAM with `ps --ppid $(pgrep zygote64) -o %mem,cmd --sort %mem` and use methods described in given link to make sure they don't run in background. Then set `Background process limit` to zero and check `Don't keep activities` in Developer Options

Comment: Thanks for clarifying 

Comment: @IrfanLatif where to run these commands in Android?

Comment: Use Termux or `adb shell`. But Android's built-in `ps` command is minimal, you need full binary.