# Phone overheats after powering on

Tags: battery, hardware, cpu

I've seen this with plenty of smartphones,usually after 1-2 years of use.The phone overheats for a minute or 2 before cooling down,but it's performance doesn't differ from a non-overheating phone that has been powered on.

Is this simply due to the natural wear and tear which causes a CPU overload for the first few minutes,or it it because of the failing/malfunctioning of a particular component in the phone/(which would in turn, adversely affect its battery life)

Comment: Well the boot process requires a lot of CPU power and if you have a lot of apps installed that start automatically after boot then this requires additional CPU power. And if your device is a bit "overpowered" (a CPU that creates way more heat as the device can release to the environment) then it may get hot. My advice: Limit the number of apps installed that start after boot (have BOOT_COMPLETED permission).

Comment: @beeshyams As far as I know changing BOOT_COMPLETED requires app repackaging. For most users (and a lot of apps) this is out of scope. Or is there a simpler way on newer devices I don't know.

Comment: I see some non root apps that claim to do this (not tested). Type "disable startup apps" in Play Store

Comment: App repackaging isn't necessarily required to disable BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast receiver. But root is mostly required: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209345/218526

Comment: This is far too broad for any specific answers. In general, yes, batteries lose capacity over time and will degrade which can cause an array of problems depending if they manage to fry anything or are sending too much/not enough electricity at the given time, and etc. Machines and the wires and metal bits are also victim to wear just from natural usage and can cause most of the same issues. Manufacturer errors and design flaws are also potential issues, along with buggy code in the OS itself.