# Shell script to stop multiple Android apps

Tags: applications, shell

My goal is to force stop multiple apps on the startup. The script can be executed with Magisk on boot by placing it in `data/adb/post-fs-data`.

I already tried writing

```
am force-stop com.exp1
```

and also with

```
#!/system/bin/sh
```

but it didn't work

What should I write on it?

Comment: See [How to run an executable on boot](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213623/218526) and [Disable autostart on boot and restrict background execution](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209345/218526).