# How do I disable auto-start in Android 11?

Tags: settings, android-11, auto-start

How can the program auto-start be controlled in Android 11?

I am using a Celero5G phone running the latest version of Android 11. I have been unable to find any help on this matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Disable autostart on boot and restrict background execution](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/209327/44325)

Comment: Yea, that's pretty useless. It's either a duplicate or not. Not. Android 11 either allows manipulation of which programs autostart, or it doesn't. Developer mode allows for this, but I am not a developer. Can it be accomplished using the Android 11 operating system ??

Comment: It's a possible duplicate since Android 4.4 and above allows manipulation of autostart. However, in most cases, there's no built-in UI for it in stock ROM. Thus, you have to rely on `adb shell`/terminal emulator app or download and use 3rd-party apps for this.

Comment: Now that is useful information. Thank you, I will follow your suggested route.