# Is there any way to prevent an app from restarting after force stopping it in the settings

Tags: applications, settings, whatsapp-messenger, force-stop

I've tried to force stop Whatsapp but after some time it restarted. This is so disgusting and apparently out of control. What can be done to prevent it from restarting.

Comment: Try to set `RUN_IN_BACKGROUND` permission to `ignore`: [Disable autostart on boot and restrict background execution](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209345/218526). But it's not guaranteed that the app won't ever start again because it uses scheduled Jobs / Alarms as well as Google Cloud Messaging to receive new messages. Also setting `WAKE_LOCK` to `ignore` may help. You can use my app [PMX](https://github.com/mirfatif/PermissionManagerX) to set both permissions conveniently.

Comment: Related: https://t.me/PermissionManagerX/2703

Comment: Did you find a working solution to this? I used to force stop Whatsapp on my Samsung A21s and it wouldn't start unless I open it myself. Now on my Samsung A33 5G, it restarts on its own.