# Prevent Spotify from starting when phone boots with AppOps

Tags: auto-start, spotify

I have an LG G7 One (not rooted) and I've been having ongoing issues with Spotify moving my downloads from my SD card to internal storage every time my phone reboots. I've done lots of research into it and it seems like the source of the problem is that Spotify starts up when the phone reboots but before the SD card has been detected by my phone, so Spotify thinks to move all downloads to internal storage.

Some workarounds I've read about:

- Moving Spotify to SD card through developer options - I can enable this option on developer options, but there's no option to actually move any of my apps to my sd card
- Force phone to ask for PIN before phone boots up (to give time to detect SD card) - no option to do this on my phone
- Prevent Spotify from starting at boot - the only way I've seen online that I can do this is the non-root solution mentioned here [Disable autostart on boot and restrict background execution](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209327/disable-autostart-on-boot-and-restrict-background-execution). I got to the step where AppOps is downloaded but I can't understand the steps from the link to deny the `BOOT_COMPLETED` permission.

I have a Mac and followed the steps here https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/ to set up ADB. I tried typing in the command `~$ appops set com.spotify.music BOOT_COMPLETED deny` but it says the command isn't recognized. Sorry for the beginner question, I'm probably making a very simple mistake (it's my first time using ADB)!

Thank you for reading and for your help! My internal storage is full even though all I have on it are essential apps and system files, while my SD card has tons of space - very frustrating :(

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. After setting up the ADB, did you call `adb shell` to enter the Android device's terminal shell?

Comment: Thank you! I did, but I get the error message "Error: Unknown operation string: BOOT_COMPLETED" when I try to run ./adb shell cmd appops set com.spotify.music BOOT_COMPLETED deny. I had asked my question on another forum as well and someone suggested that maybe BOOT_COMPLETED isn't an official permission on android if I'm not rooted. Do you know if that's true?